# PySpark WithColumn on multiple columns with udf

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a function in PySpark that takes two input and returns **two output**:

```
def get_seen_cards(x, y):
    if 1 in x:
        alreadyFailed = 1
    else:
        alreadyFailed = 0
    if y:
        alreadyAuthorized = 1
    else:
        alreadyAuthorized = 0
return alreadyFailed, alreadyAuthorized
```

And I want to apply this function with udf to get the whole dataframe treated like this:

```
get_seen_cards_udf = udf(lambda x, y : get_seen_cards_spark(x, y), IntegerType())

data.withColumn(["alr_failed", "alr_auth"], get_seen_cards_udf(data["card_uid"], data["failed"]))
```

Where `data["card_uid"]` looks like this :

```
[Row(card_uid='card_1'),
 Row(card_uid='card_2'),
 Row(card_uid='card_3'),
 Row(card_uid='card_4'),
 Row(card_uid='card_5')]
```

and `data["failed"]` look like this :

```
[Row(failed=False),
 Row(failed=False),
 Row(failed=False),
 Row(failed=True),
 Row(failed=False)]
```

But this is obvioulsy not working because *withColumn* only works for **one column**.

I need to add two columns at the same time in my dataframe, the first is the results of the first return of the function and will be stored in "`alr_failed`" and the other column is the second value of the return and will be store in "`alr_auth`".

The idea is to return a dataframe with the following columns after treatment :

```
card_uid, failed, alr_failed, alr_auth
```

Is it even possible someway ? Or is there's a workaround for this ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, how do you decide which column of your data goes into which argument? Do you want it for every combination of two columns? It would help to share actual data and code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Well, the return from "a" goes to "success" and the return from "b" goes to "failed". I don't know if I'm clear so I'll update my post now

Comment: This is edited, don't hesitate to tell me if you still don't understand

Comment: I think the logical thing would be to split your function into two separate functions for each column type.

Comment: Yes I think too but I was wondering is there were a possibility to do it otherwise

Comment: Could create an `Array` column and split it afterwards perhaps.